# REST good practices: new resource or parameter?

Tags: java, web-services, http, rest, url

I'm designing a RESTful API and I have a pretty simple "philosophical" question:

I have a resource representing a set of values stored in a period of time:

**loggers/2/data?begin=10h&end=12h**

Doing this request I get the data stored by a Data Logger (with id=2) from 10:00h to 12:00h.

response:

```
[
{
    "data": "10h",
    "value": 10
},
{
    "data": "11h",
    "value": 15
},
{
    "data": "12h",
    "value": 9
}
]
```

Now, I want only the max value in this period:

```
[
{
    "data": "11h",
    "value": 15
}
]
```

So... Is this a new resource? like:

**loggers/2/data/max?begin=10h&end=12h**

or the same resource filtered?

**loggers/2/data?begin=10h&end=12h&filter=max**

What do you think? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a new resource as it's kind-of corresponding to a new *method* for the given entity.

In my WebApp I use the following format:

1. To *invoke methods* of a given entity instance `/entity/method/id` eg `/user/retrieve/5` or `/user/settings/5`
2. To *invoke static methods* `/entity/method` eg `/user/create` or `/user/oldest`
3. No method would default to the classic "list all" eg `/user` (I might have decided to do `/user/all`